# Getting 404 for original video files, called with file_create_url

Tags: files

I am facing a strange problem.

**Environment**

1. Drupal 7.23
2. [Video](https://drupal.org/project/video) Module
3. File system Writable (public download method)

When i trued a custom HTML5 Player from MediaElementjs its not loading video. But when i try with a video file from external server its also working.

Take a look at the Screens. Please let me know if you need any more information.

**Note : I can't get the file directly with the browser as well.** When i try `file_create_url` and place the link in browser, still no luck.

[image]

[image]